# Count pages UNO Java

Tags: java, libreoffice, uno

What is the best way to count the number of pages in a `LibreOffice` document in Java using `UNO`?

I tried googling but nothing useful turned up. I'm a beginner at `UNO`.

Comment: Entering "openoffice macro count pages" (without quotes) in Google brings up several good results  Yes, it's LibreOffice, but "openoffice" produces more results and they're usually relevant.  Also "macro" or possibly "uno api" are good keywords for Google.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way: Get the PageCount property of [TextDocumentView](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextDocumentView.html).

```
xComponent = xDesktop.getCurrentComponent();
xTextDocument = (com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
        com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument.class, xComponent);
XController xController = xTextDocument.getCurrentController();
XPropertySet xPropertySet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XPropertySet.class, xController);
int nPageCount = AnyConverter.toInt(
    xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("PageCount"));
System.out.println("There are " + nPageCount + " pages.")
```

The harder way: Find the PageCount value in the list of [XDocumentProperties](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/XDocumentProperties.html).

```
xComponent = xDesktop.getCurrentComponent();
xTextDocument = (com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
        com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument.class, xComponent);
XDocumentPropertiesSupplier xSupplier = (XDocumentPropertiesSupplier)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
        XDocumentPropertiesSupplier.class, xTextDocument);
XDocumentProperties xProps = (XDocumentProperties)
    xSupplier.getDocumentProperties();
NamedValue [] aStats = xProps.getDocumentStatistics();
for (int i = 0; i < aStats.length; i++) {
    if (aStats[i].Name.equals("PageCount")) {
        System.out.println("Page Count " + aStats[i].Value);
    }
}
```

This question was also answered at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=56507.  Also see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=17358 for answers mostly in Basic.